# Letters from two lines are interchanged, Adobe Reader can do the job

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a question with regard to pdfbox 1.8.13. I am trying to read in the entire text from a one page PDF document. Adobe Reader can do the job, pdfbox reads almost the entire page but scrambles the first two lines of the document and the last two lines of the document so that letters are interchanged.

Does anybody know how to solve such an issue? First, where to ask, second, how can I share the PDF with you, and Third, does someone have the possibility to check whether the problem also exists in version 2.0.7 of pdfbox, which I understodd is completely different and thus not straightforward to implement?

Thank you in advance for your help
Stephan

Adobe Reader:

```
ScalableCapitalHRB217778,AmtsgerichtMünchenSeite1von1 
VermögensverwaltungGmbHUSt-IdNr.DE300434774 
Prinzregentenstr. 
48Geschäftsführung:80538München 
ErikPodzuweit,FlorianPrucker
```

pdfbox:

```
SVecramlaöbgleenCsavpeitrawlaltung GmbH UHSRtB-I2d1N7r7.7D8E,3A0m0t4s3g4e7ri7c4ht München Seite 1 von 1
8P0ri5n3zr8egMeünntcehnesntr. 48 GEreikscPhoädftzsufwüheritu,nFglo: rian Prucker
```

Link to the PDF (I have verified that the problem is the same with the unmodified and the modified PDF that I have uploaded):

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5930649bce9a1d1a686a0da63f1b9bce20170808071518/9b9140

P.S.: In the meanwhile, I have also tried the PDDocument.loadNonSeq version in pdfbox 1.8.13 but this resulted in the same problem.

Comment: Upload the PDF to a sharehoster and then post the link, e.g. dropbox, google drive, wikisend, filedropper, etc

Comment: You can also test with the ExtractText command line application. Just download pdfbox-app from the download site.

Comment: It is definitively better with 2.0.7. The API for simple text extraction is the same.

Comment: You don't show the code you used to do the text extraction. This makes helping difficult.

Comment: @mkl he used the sort option. This brings the crappy results in 1.8 (but not in 2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @tilman-hausherr for your helpful hints. With them, I managed to debug my problem.

You were right that leaving out the sorting option (I don't know why it was used before in the project that I now work on) resolved the scrambling issue even in `pdfbox-1.8.13`. And you were right that the text extraction result using `pdfbox-2.0.7` gave even better results.

The relevant Java code snippets that I was using with `pdfbox-1.8.13` were:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
...
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
textStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
String text = textStripper.getText(doc);
```

If I understand correctly, the API for simple text extraction going from `pdfbox-1.8.13` to `pdfbox-2.0.7` is not the same, but very similar, the `PDFTextStripper` has just been moved from `util` to `text`:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
...
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
// textStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
String text = textStripper.getText(doc);
```

To find out about all of this, as you said the command line tool was very helpful and here are the results of the text extraction with the different options (https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html and https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html):

java -jar pdfbox-app-1.8.13.jar ExtractText -sort "20170801 Rechnung.pdf":

```
SVecramlaöbgleenCsavpeitrawl HRBPrinzregentenstra.l4tu8ng GmbH GUSest-I
2d1N7r7.7D8E,3A0m0t4s3g4e7ri7c4ht München Seite 1 von 1
80538 München ErikcPhoädftzsufwüheritu,nFglo: rian Prucker
```

java -jar pdfbox-app-1.8.13.jar ExtractText "20170801 Rechnung.pdf":

```
Scalable CapitalVermögensverwaltung GmbHPrinzregentenstr. 4880538 München
HRB 217778, Amtsgericht MünchenUSt-IdNr. DE300434774Geschäftsführung:Erik 
Podzuweit, Florian Prucker
Seite 1 von 1
```

java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.7.jar ExtractText -sort "20170801 Rechnung.pdf":

```
Scalable Capital HRB 217778, Amtsgericht München Seite 1 von 1
Vermögensverwaltung GmbH USt-IdNr. DE300434774
Prinzregentenstr. 48 Geschäftsführung:
80538 München Erik Podzuweit, Florian Prucker
```

java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.7.jar ExtractText "20170801 Rechnung.pdf"

```
Scalable Capital
Vermögensverwaltung GmbH
Prinzregentenstr. 48
80538 München
HRB 217778, Amtsgericht München
USt-IdNr. DE300434774
Geschäftsführung:
Erik Podzuweit, Florian Prucker
Seite 1 von 1
```

So I think `pdfbox-2.0.7` gives the nicest results in this case, especially without the `-sort` option, even if I don't know why the algorithms behave differently, since `pdfbox-1.8.3` gave the same result with or without the `-nonSeq` option.

Comment: While it may be true that for your documents using the `sort` option is not a good idea, readers of this answer should be aware that there also are many PDFs extracting from which *without* that option results in utter nonsense.

Comment: Can you explain why this is or whether one can ask the creater of the PDF to correct / modify this behaviour?

Comment: *"why this is"* - PDF originally is a format for *displaying* documents identically across platforms. Additional features like *text extraction* are optional.   *"correct this behaviour"* - that's difficult because the behaviour is not incorrect to start with, see above. *"modify this behaviour"* - you can ask the creator to create properly tagged PDFs so you can apply text extraction based on tagging information.

Comment: The creator may not even know that his/her PDFs have glyphs in weird orders - PDFs are created by computers. The programmer of an invoice may want to start with the top and the bottom, then the items and then the sum. However the sequence might be different too and it would still look the same.

Comment: Why did it fail in 1.8 when sorted? I think it is because the font wasn't read correctly. PDFBox had a lot of troubles with fonts, maybe it didn't get the size properly and because of that, it thought that all was part of the same line. (Rendering the file with 1.8 looks very crappy)